# Returning the model in Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying Sails JS and trying to display a simple record, but the records doesn't seem to be displaying. I have the code below, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**model:**

module.exports = {

```
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    Name: {
        type: 'string'
    }
  },

  listAll: function(res, cb){
    Programmes.query('Select * from programmes', function(err, queryResult){
        cb(err, queryResult);
    });
  }
};
```

**Controller:**

```
  view: function (req, res) {

    var myresult;
    Programmes.listAll(res, function(err, result){
      var myresult = JSON.stringify(result);
      console.log('CONTROLLER:' + myresult)      
    });

    return res.view('Programmes/listAll', {Model : myresult });
  },
```

**View:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        This is a test!
        <%_.each(Model, function(myList){%>
            <p>id: <%= myList.id%></p>
        <% })%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is happening?  Are you seeing the console log?  Are you seeing the view and "This is a test!", but no data?

Comment: Yes, the console is displaying the records in Json but on the html "This is a test!" is shown but no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findAll` method is asynchronous, but you're treating it like a synchronous function by placing `res.view` after it and expecting the `myresult` var to be instantiated. Move `res.view` inside the callback for `listAll` (directly after `console.log`) and it should work fine.